# The problem is with retrofit when running on a physical device

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, samsung-galaxy

I have a problem: I'm writing a weather app, using retrofit 2.0. When I run the app on the emulator, everything works fine(API 24, 28, 29). But today I launched my app on a physical device (Galaxy A21s, version android 10) and the request to the server is not working. The request works onResponse() but it comes with response.body () = = null and response.is Successful == null. But everything works in the emulator!
Can you tell us what the problem is and how to solve it?

```
class DataProcessing {
    private val retrofitImpl: RetrofitImpl = RetrofitImpl()
    private val mainActivity = MainActivity()
    internal fun sendRequest(townName:String, instance : DataProcessingCallback){
            retrofitImpl.getRequest().showWeather(townName).enqueue(object : Callback<DateWeather> {
                override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<DateWeather>, response: Response<DateWeather>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                        processingData(response.body(), null, instance)
                    } else
                        processingData(null, Throwable("ответ не получен"), instance)
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DateWeather>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Main", "onFailure")
                    processingData(null, t, instance)
                }
            })
        }
            private fun processingData(dateWeather:DateWeather?, error: Throwable?, instance : DataProcessingCallback){
            if (dateWeather == null || error != null) {
                Log.d("Egor", "error: ${error!!.message.toString()}")
                instance.showToastText("Произошла ошибка \n Возможно вы неправильно ввели название населенного пункта")
            } else {
                if (dateWeather == null) Log.d("Main", "Loose")
                else {
                    val string = dateWeather.weather.get(0).toString()
                    val size = string.length - 1
                    instance.onSuccessfulDataProcessed(string.subSequence(13, size).toString(), dateWeather.main.temp!!.toInt())
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

```
interface ShowWeather{
    @GET("weather?&appid=(TOKEN)&units=metric")// there is a token here, I just deleted it when publishing, everything is fine with it
    fun showWeather(@Query("q") town: String): Call<DateWeather>
}
```

```
class RetrofitImpl{
    fun getRequest() : ShowWeather{
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        return retrofitBuilder.create(ShowWeather::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
data class DateWeather(
    val main: Main,
    val weather : List<Weather>

)

data class Main(
    val temp : Double?
)
data class Weather(
        val main: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

At a base URL, you are trying with http unsecured connection. Can you check with "https://" instead of "http://"

```
val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error turned out to be elementary: on a physical device, I used a hint (T9) that returned the city. After the name of the city there was a gap and this was the error. trim () solved my problem.
@Kishore A, thank you so much for your help!

```
townName = editText.getText().trim().toString()
```